# Access LDAP SSO user name from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I'm quite new with Laravel, so my question may sound stupid to you...
I already found something out in the wild which might address my question, but they are talking about middleware which I neither understand nor can adopt to my project.

I have a scenario where users access my site using their windows login names. The authentication is done using SSO and apache .htaccess file.
The user name is accessible via $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] on plain PHP.
Unfortunately, I cannot use this global variable in Laravel.
Also all the hints from the Internet (using \Auth::user() or auth()->user()) do not work...

Anything I can do here (without to much highly sophisticated magic I do not (yet) understand)?

Best regards,
Tom

Comment: Middlewares are no magic. They are part of the basics and belong to Laravels foundation. You should check out the architecture concepts and basics in the docs. I'm quite sure you'll be able to solve it on your own then.

Comment: In the meantime, I don't think that my biggest problem is the middleware stuff. It seems as if there's no way to have .htaccess files for the different routes and to use the browser's authentication passthrough mechanisms with Laravel. I've configured `AuthType Kerberos` in .htaccess...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your goal correctly. Do you want all users which were authenticated by Apaache to be able to access your _whole_ application (as if there were no users directly in your application)? Or do you want to authenticate application users based on their SSO? There are Laravel packages for LDAP out there already, so maybe you look into this direction?

Comment: In my current setup, only users with an AD account should be able to access the application. I do not want them to authenticate using user names and passwords, as they are already authenticated on their PCs. The browser should forward the authentication information (Kerberos ticket) and the web server should then take care of the authorization. In my application, I would then like to use the login name of the user (as given in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`) to filter some database queries. People without an Active Directory account will be blocked directly by Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy...
Please excuse my stupidity!
I didn't see the forest for the trees.
Of course, when using `php artisan serve` I cannot expect to have the same scenario as in the actual target directory! Also, there's no apache web server running but Laravel's internal server.
The solution was, that I don't need any middleware stuff or some magic. All I needed is already there! I now can access the `REMOTE_USER` variable by using `request()->server('REMOTE_USER')`.
All I have to do is switch from the Laravel internal web server to my production Apache web server and to the production environment. Then all the values are there as expected.

I saw a similar question like mine several times in different forums and maybe they made the same mistake... So, if anyone stumbles across this phenomen: please keep the web server in mind ;-)

Thanks for your hints and sorry for bothering you with this silly question.